# Android: call a method from calling activity

Tags: android, android-activity

In my activity, on user's request for preferences screen, I call:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, Preferences.class));
```

Preferences class is defined like this:

```
public class Preferences extends PreferenceActivity implements OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener {
    ...
    public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences prefs, String key) {
        ...
    }

}
```

I need to implement OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener in my Preferences class becase I want to be able to - for example - disable a preferences item based on a specific selection.
But I would need to implement it in my main Activity, to react to the preference changes.

Unfortunately onSharedPreferenceChanged() fires only in my Preferences class, and not in my main activity: how can I force it to be fired in bot activities?

Or - how can I manually call onSharedPreferenceChanged() in my main activity from onSharedPreferenceChanged() in Preferences activity?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in your main activity, you can register a listener for prefs changes:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
    .getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
prefs.registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

and then you would implement `SharedPreferences.OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener` in your activity, with your own `onSharedPreferenceChanged` method.

Comment: Thanks!!! I did already do registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener() in my main activity, but for some reason it was commented out! Thanks for your propmtness...

Answer (score 1):

Well, there's little sense in watching for preferences change in an activity that's not currently 'active'. You should handle your main activity's lifecycle events instead such as `onResume`, `onRestart` etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make some functionality accessible from both activities, you best do this by including this code into a static method which can be called from anywhere. In Android activities are decoupled, you don't really have the access from one activity to the instance of some other activity.